Showing the supreme function is not Lebesgue integrable.
Let $\mu$ be Lebesgue measure on $[0, 1]$. Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of integrable functions on $[0, 1]$ with values in $[0, \infty)$ such that for all $n$
\begin{align*}
    \int_{[0,1]}f_n\text{d}\mu = 1
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
    \int_{(1/n, 1]}f_n\text{d}\mu \leq \frac{1}{n}.
\end{align*}
Let $g=\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \{f_n\}$. Show that $g$ is not integrable.
Edit:
My attempt is as the following:
Denote $E_n = \{x:|f_n(x)|\geq \epsilon\}$. By Chebychev's inequality, given $\epsilon>0$, we have $\mu(E_n)\leq \frac{1}{n\epsilon}$ on $(\frac{1}{n}, 1]$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty} \mu(E_n) = 0$ meaning $f_n$ converges to $0$ pointwise. By Egoroff's theorem, $f_n$ converges to $0$ uniformly when $n\to\infty$. Suppose $g$ is integrable. Then by Lebesgue dominated convergence, since $f_n\leq g$, $\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{[0,1]} f_n \text{d}\mu = \int_{[0,1]} 0  \text{d}\mu = 0$, contradicting to $ \int_{[0,1]}f_n\text{d}\mu = 1$, meaning $g$ is not integrable.
My Question:
I'm not sure if my solution is valid. Can someone tell me if there are any flaws in it? Thanks!

Welcome to MSE. In this forum you're expected to show some effort in order to get help. Edit your question to include your work on the problem to avoid your question to be downvoted and eventually closed. This is not a homework service.

To avoid getting downvoted into oblivion, I recommend adding some context. What lead you to this question? What have you attempted? What theorems do you know which might be helpful?

Sorry for the incomplete information. Just updated my question. @jjagmath

@JMM Hi, I already updated my solution. Feel free to check it out!

No mistake jumps out at me, but I thought it's a theorem that the supremum of measurable functions is measurable, so something feels fishy. Anyway I am no measure theory expert, maybe someone else can give better insight.

You proved that $f_n$ converges to $0$ in measure, not pointwise. Only then you can take a subsequence that converges pointwise. Then you apply Lebesgue dominated convergence to that subsequence assuming $g$ is integrable and get a contradiction. You don't need any uniform convergence and Egorov's theorem.

@SamedyMaj Thanks! The idea to use a subsequence sounds good to me!
